# How to extract rows with specific columns and values between two data tables?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr

I have two sorted data tables (A and B), in table A, 3 first columns are genomic coordinates. 
I like to extract some specific rows from A table but based on some common columns/values of B table.

For example: First, I would like to match the column 'ID' of A table and  B table, then if there is a `1` value in the 'strand' column of B table, select those rows (from A table) which have the same value (first match) in the 'Value' column of A and B tables and the coordinates before. But if there is a `- 1` value in the 'strand' column of B table, select those rows (from A table) which have the same value (last match) in the 'Value' column of A and B tables and the coordinates after.

```
mydf1 <- structure(list(chr = c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"), start = c(50094737L, 50096132L, 50097423L, 50105371L, 50109957L, 50109957L, 50109957L, 22987417L, 22999579L, 23004425L, 23005372L, 23006728L, 23015638L, 23017252L, 119539386L, 119541328L, 119544353L, 119560268L, 119565232L, 14518560L, 14521158L, 14521869L, 14530332L, 14553322L, 14571763L, 14572229L, 14667634L, 14774253L), end = c(50094898L, 50096286L, 50097564L, 50105442L, 50111058L, 50111368L, 50112152L, 22987563L, 23000105L, 23004626L, 23005475L, 23007746L, 23015743L, 23020199L, 119539789L, 119541420L, 119544491L, 119560385L, 119565401L, 14521306L, 14521306L, 14522019L, 14530515L, 14553387L, 14572189L, 14572314L, 14667691L, 14774897L), Value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Tx = c("ENST00000007708", "ENST00000007708", "ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357", "ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357", "ENST00000007708", "ENST00000614357", "ENST00000503176", "ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822", "ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000644802", "ENST00000181796", "ENST00000479731", "ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467", "ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000479731", "ENST00000181796", "ENST00000181796"), ID = c("ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 28L))
mydf2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000065809"), name = c("PDK2", "RHOBTB2", "CXorf56", "FAM107B"), strand = c(1L, 1L, -1L, -1L), Value = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
```

Input A:

```
mydf1

chr start       end       Value Tx              ID
17  50094737    50094898    1   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50096132    50096286    2   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50097423    50097564    3   ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
17  50105371    50105442    3   ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
17  50109957    50111058    1   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50109957    50111368    2   ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882 
17  50109957    50112152    1   ENST00000503176 ENSG00000005882 
8   22987417    22987563    2   ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853 
8   22999579    23000105    1   ENST00000251822 ENSG00000008853 
8   23004425    23004626    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23005372    23005475    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23006728    23007746    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23015638    23015743    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23017252    23020199    1   ENST00000251822 ENSG00000008853 
X   119539386   119539789   1   ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610 
X   119541328   119541420   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119544353   119544491   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119560268   119560385   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119565232   119565401   1   ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610 
10  14518560    14521306    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 
10  14521158    14521306    1   ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809 
10  14521869    14522019    8    ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567    ENSG00000065809
10  14530332    14530515    8    ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567    ENSG00000065809
10  14553322    14553387    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467 ENSG00000065809
10  14571763    14572189    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567 ENSG00000065809
10  14572229    14572314    1   ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809 
10  14667634    14667691    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 
10  14774253    14774897    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809
```

Input B:

```
mydf2 

ID              name  strand Value
ENSG00000005882 PDK2     1  3
ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2  1  2
ENSG00000018610 CXorf56 -1  2
ENSG00000065809 FAM107B -1  8
```

Desire Output:

```
17  50094737    50094898    1   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50096132    50096286    2   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50097423    50097564    3   ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
8   22987417    22987563    2   ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853 
X   119560268   119560385   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119565232   119565401   1   ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610 
10  14530332    14530515    8   ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567 ENSG00000065809
10  14553322    14553387    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467 ENSG00000065809
10  14571763    14572189    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567 ENSG00000065809
10  14572229    14572314    1   ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809 
10  14667634    14667691    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 
10  14774253    14774897    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809
```

I have tried with `dyplr` and `ifelse` but I couldn`t get what I want.

Thanks a lot in advance for any possible solution!

Comment: Hey, can you provide a `dput()` output for each of your tables?

Comment: Could you use column names instead of "column six", "fourth column", etc.? Seems like the first step is to `left_join` tables A and B, which makes it a little hard to track column orders, and you are using `dplyr` which encourages exclusive use of column names.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated with column name.

Comment: could you specify what you mean exactly with "coordinates before/ after"?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion   http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/ please make the question clearer. It looks interesting, but it's really not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to extract all rows from `mydf1` for each matching `ID`

- from the first row of the `ID` group until the first matching `Value` if `strand == 1`
- from the last matching `Value` to the last row of the `ID` group if `strand == -1`.

The approach below uses *non-equi joins* which are available with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

# coerce to data.table and append row number
setDT(mydf1)[, rn := .I]
setDT(mydf2)

# pick first rows
tmpf <- mydf1[mydf2[strand == 1], on = .(ID, Value), mult = "first", .(ID, rn)]
resf <- mydf1[tmpf, on = .(ID, rn <= rn)]

# pick last rows
tmpl <- mydf1[mydf2[strand == -1], on = .(ID, Value), mult = "last", .(ID, rn)]
resl <- mydf1[tmpl, on = .(ID, rn >= rn)]

# combine both partial results, remove row numbers
rbind(resf, resl)[, rn:= NULL][]
```

> ```
>     chr     start       end Value                                                 Tx              ID
>  1:  17  50094737  50094898     1                                    ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882
>  2:  17  50096132  50096286     2                                    ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882
>  3:  17  50097423  50097564     3    ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
>  4:   8  22987417  22987563     2                                    ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
>  5:   X 119560268 119560385     2                    ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
>  6:   X 119565232 119565401     1                                    ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
>  7:  10  14530332  14530515     8 ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467... ENSG00000065809
>  8:  10  14553322  14553387     2                    ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467 ENSG00000065809
>  9:  10  14571763  14572189     2                    ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567 ENSG00000065809
> 10:  10  14572229  14572314     1                                    ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809
> 11:  10  14667634  14667691     1                                    ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809
> 12:  10  14774253  14774897     1                                    ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809
> ```

#### Explanation

**To be completed**

#### Data

The `fread()` function from `data.table` is also capable to read the data as provided by the OP:

```
library(data.table)

mydf1 <- fread( "chr start       end       Value Tx              ID
17  50094737    50094898    1   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50096132    50096286    2   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50097423    50097564    3   ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
17  50105371    50105442    3   ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882
17  50109957    50111058    1   ENST00000007708 ENSG00000005882 
17  50109957    50111368    2   ENST00000614357 ENSG00000005882 
17  50109957    50112152    1   ENST00000503176 ENSG00000005882 
8   22987417    22987563    2   ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853 
8   22999579    23000105    1   ENST00000251822 ENSG00000008853 
8   23004425    23004626    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23005372    23005475    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23006728    23007746    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23015638    23015743    2   ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685 ENSG00000008853
8   23017252    23020199    1   ENST00000251822 ENSG00000008853 
X   119539386   119539789   1   ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610 
X   119541328   119541420   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119544353   119544491   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119560268   119560385   2   ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610
X   119565232   119565401   1   ENST00000644802 ENSG00000018610 
10  14518560    14521306    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 
10  14521158    14521306    1   ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809 
10  14521869    14522019    8    ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567    ENSG00000065809
10  14530332    14530515    8    ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567    ENSG00000065809
10  14553322    14553387    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467 ENSG00000065809
10  14571763    14572189    2   ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567 ENSG00000065809
10  14572229    14572314    1   ENST00000479731 ENSG00000065809 
10  14667634    14667691    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 
10  14774253    14774897    1   ENST00000181796 ENSG00000065809 ")

mydf2 <- fread("ID              name  strand Value
ENSG00000005882 PDK2     1  3
ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2  1  2
ENSG00000018610 CXorf56 -1  2
ENSG00000065809 FAM107B -1  8")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

I have taken the liberty to convert your example data frames using [this unfortunately little know awesome package](https://github.com/alistaire47/read.so) into a reproducible example. Your question is unfortunately somewhat obscure, but sounds generally interesting enough to work on.

```r
mydf1 <- structure(list(chr = c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"), start = c(50094737L, 50096132L, 50097423L, 50105371L, 50109957L, 50109957L, 50109957L, 22987417L, 22999579L, 23004425L, 23005372L, 23006728L, 23015638L, 23017252L, 119539386L, 119541328L, 119544353L, 119560268L, 119565232L, 14518560L, 14521158L, 14521869L, 14530332L, 14553322L, 14571763L, 14572229L, 14667634L, 14774253L), end = c(50094898L, 50096286L, 50097564L, 50105442L, 50111058L, 50111368L, 50112152L, 22987563L, 23000105L, 23004626L, 23005475L, 23007746L, 23015743L, 23020199L, 119539789L, 119541420L, 119544491L, 119560385L, 119565401L, 14521306L, 14521306L, 14522019L, 14530515L, 14553387L, 14572189L, 14572314L, 14667691L, 14774897L), Value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Tx = c("ENST00000007708", "ENST00000007708", "ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357", "ENST00000007708,ENST00000503176,ENST00000614357", "ENST00000007708", "ENST00000614357", "ENST00000503176", "ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822,ENST00000519685", "ENST00000251822", "ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000320339,ENST00000644802", "ENST00000644802", "ENST00000181796", "ENST00000479731", "ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000181796,ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467,ENST00000378470,ENST00000468747,ENST00000478076,ENST00000479731,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000378458,ENST00000378467", "ENST00000378458,ENST00000622567", "ENST00000479731", "ENST00000181796", "ENST00000181796"), ID = c("ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809", "ENSG00000065809")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 28L))
mydf2 <- structure(list(ID = c("ENSG00000005882", "ENSG00000008853", "ENSG00000018610", "ENSG00000065809"), name = c("PDK2", "RHOBTB2", "CXorf56", "FAM107B"), strand = c(1L, 1L, -1L, -1L), Value = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))

library(tidyverse)

mymerge <- 
  left_join(mydf1, mydf2, by = c('ID', 'Value')) %>% 
  slice(c(which(strand == 1), which(strand == 1)-1,
        which(strand == -1), which(strand == -1)+1)) %>% 
    distinct %>% # there will be some duplicate rows, remove them
    select(-Tx) %>% arrange(chr) # both steps just for demonstration

mymerge  
#>    chr     start       end Value              ID    name strand
#> 1   10  14521869  14522019     8 ENSG00000065809 FAM107B     -1
#> 2   10  14530332  14530515     8 ENSG00000065809 FAM107B     -1
#> 3   10  14553322  14553387     2 ENSG00000065809    <NA>     NA
#> 4   17  50097423  50097564     3 ENSG00000005882    PDK2      1
#> 5   17  50105371  50105442     3 ENSG00000005882    PDK2      1
#> 6   17  50096132  50096286     2 ENSG00000005882    <NA>     NA
#> 7   17  50109957  50112152     1 ENSG00000005882    <NA>     NA
#> 8    8  22987417  22987563     2 ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2      1
#> 9    8  23004425  23004626     2 ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2      1
#> 10   8  23005372  23005475     2 ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2      1
#> 11   8  23006728  23007746     2 ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2      1
#> 12   8  23015638  23015743     2 ENSG00000008853 RHOBTB2      1
#> 13   8  22999579  23000105     1 ENSG00000008853    <NA>     NA
#> 14   X 119541328 119541420     2 ENSG00000018610 CXorf56     -1
#> 15   X 119544353 119544491     2 ENSG00000018610 CXorf56     -1
#> 16   X 119560268 119560385     2 ENSG00000018610 CXorf56     -1
#> 17   X 119565232 119565401     1 ENSG00000018610    <NA>     NA
```

Now, what I did, I created indices using `slice`, after merging as suggested by @Steve. 
Your desired output differs from mine - this is because I don't really understand what you mean. My solution might not entirely be what you want, or your desired output is not entirely what you want.

<sup>Created on 2019-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Didn't know about the `read.so` package it's indeed brilliant and thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult without a `dput()` output of your dataframes provided, but I'll take a crack at it:

```
t <- left_join(A, B, by=c(ID, Value)) # Join the two tables together by ID and Value

first_occ <- t %>% group_by(strand) %>% filter(row_number() == min(row_number())) # select first occurrence
last_occ <- t %>% group_by(strand) %>% filter(row_number() == max(row_number())) # select last occurrence
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it looks good, but I want to have coordinates lower than the first ID match (if the strand is 1) and bigger coordinates than the last ID match (if the strand is -1)